# Hot reload gevent WSGIServer

Tags: python, wsgi, gevent

I've got a `Flask` app nicely running in a `gevent.WSGIServer`. For that smooth development experience I would like to enable hot-reload, e.g. if a python loaded python file changes on disk, I would like the server to reload. As I use SSE events that necessarily blocks requests, so I cannot run the otherwise very nice Flask built-in debug server. In production I do not want hot-reload.

I found the `@run_with_reloader` decorator, but 1) in a code comment the authors advice against using this function and 2) When *any* function in my main py-file has this decorator hot-reload is always enabled, regardless of that function being called or not.

How can I hot-reload a `gevent.WSGIServer` during development?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same use case. I found this, and it's working, though it's using twisted: https://gist.github.com/ianschenck/977379a91154fe264897 . A similar approach could work for gevent too.

Comment: ah, yes. That's what I found as well. It works mostly well with some quirks. I was worried about the comment here. https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/master/werkzeug/serving.py#L744

Answer (score 5):

I think this is the best answer. Works for me.

```
import gevent.wsgi
import werkzeug.serving

@werkzeug.serving.run_with_reloader
def runServer():
    app.debug = True

    ws = gevent.wsgi.WSGIServer(('', 5000), app)
    ws.serve_forever()
```

attach the original link:
http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/34/

Comment: werkzeug.serving.run_with_reloader has been made private for newer version of flask